# What HTML tags to display video preview in iMessage?

Tags: markup, imessage

I'm trying to understand how Amazon does it to make this page play a video preview when its link is sent in iMessage:
[https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Fire-TV-Stick-With-Alexa-Voice-Remote-Streaming-Media-Player/dp/B00ZV9RDKK/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1495387130&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ZV9RDKK)

After a bit of research, I've read multiple times that OGP og:video tags do the trick, however that page contains none.
The video that shows in iMessage is the one that appears as the last product image. 
Any idea?